# How to delete file in minIO storage in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, storage, minio

I used the minIO storage in my Django app.I want to delete the object from DB and storage.What can I do?
thanks in advance.
this is my model:

```
class FileStorage(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name = 'storage_team', null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    video = models.FileField(verbose_name="Object Upload",
                            storage=MinioBackend(bucket_name=priv_bucket),
                            upload_to=iso_date_prefix)
                            
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a minio client in python and call the `remove_object`  function. Refer [here](https://github.com/minio/minio-py/blob/master/examples/remove_object.py)

Answer (score 0):

'''
by default delete will delete the row from the table but the object will not be deleted. To delete the object from the minio storage you need to override the default delete method of django. Just write the delete method like this:
'''

```
class FileStorage(models.Model):
        team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name = 'storage_team', null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        title = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
        video = models.FileField(verbose_name="Object Upload",
                                storage=MinioBackend(bucket_name=priv_bucket),
                                upload_to=iso_date_prefix)   
    
        def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.video.delete()
            super(FileStorage, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```